# DSC with xActiveDirectory: Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed

Tags: azure, active-directory, dsc, domaincontroller

I'm starting to become a big fan of "Desired State Configuration" (DSC). Great work so far, guys!

Im using the "xActiveDirectory" script (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xActiveDirectory-f2d573f3) published a few weeks ago. As soon as the VM is deployed in Azure, I get the following error:

Job {860932CF-ECE2-11E4-80BB-0003FF54BC14} : 
This event indicates that a non-terminating error was thrown when DSCEngine was executing Set-TargetResource on MSFT_xADDomain DSC resource. FullyQualifiedErrorId is Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.General.77,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShell.Commands.InstallADDSForestCommand. ErrorMessage is **Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed. The specified argument 'DataBasePath' was not recognized.**

As I can see so far, my machine has been become a DC so I dont understand this error. I really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the domain credentials you are passing to the DSC resource are correct.  I've seen this issue and have confirmed that if I don't pass the correct $DomainAdministratorCredential I receive the same error.

Comment: This was the reason! Thank you